# It is possible in Javascript to redefine the function used to access to an object property?

Tags: javascript

When I perform some tests I need to declare an object with several properties, usually equal to a dummy function/value.

In Python there is the possibility to define, through the method `__get__` the function invoked when accessing to an object property, so that the property can be computed at runtime.

There is the same possibility in Javascript or some workaround?

What I want to do is to have an `Object x` where `x[whatever_it_is]` is equal to a value defined by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Proxies to imitate `__get__` using handlers with a `get` trap:

```
var handler = {
    get:: function(obj, prop) {
        // return some value here
        if (prop === "name") 
            return "Foo"
        return obj.prop
    }
}

var proxy = new Proxy(dummyObj, handler)

console.log(proxy.name) // => Foo
```

Answer (score 2):

[setters in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)
or [Proxy in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) or [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)
can help to solve your task.

Comment: A expand explanation/summary or example would make this answer more robust.

Comment: Seems like getters and setters wouldn't be what he's looking for, but Proxy would.

Comment: Proxy is exactly what I was looking for...
```new Proxy({}, {
                    get: () => {
                        return () => {};
                    },
                })```
For example with this code I can say that every property is a dummy function